# CE Image query strings params?

Tags: ce-image

Is possible to use CE Image in the same way of timthumb? for example, this image:

```
timthumb.php?src=//mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/WebStatic/Images/Static/109/slide-1.jpg&w=1280
```

can be used with CE Image? something similar to:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="//mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/WebStatic/Images/Static/109/slide-1.jpg"}&w=1280
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `width` parameter.

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="//mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/WebStatic/Images/Static/109/slide-1.jpg" width="1280"}
```

[See all the available parameters for CE Image.](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters)

Comment: Unfortunately, width size is added dynamically by a script at the end of the file. jpg

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to resize the image located at `//mysite.s3.amazonaws.com/WebStatic/Images/Static/109/slide-1.jpg` to be 1280 pixels wide?